# XPath not working as expected [php]

Tags: php, xpath

I often use XPath with php for parsing pages,
but this time i don't understand the behavior with this specific page with the following code, I hope you can help me on this.

Code that I use to parse this page http://www.jeuxvideo.com/recherche.php?m=9&t=10&q=Call+of+duty :

```
<?php
$What = 'Call of duty';
$What = urlencode($What);
$Query = 'http://www.jeuxvideo.com/recherche.php?m=9&t=10&q='.$What;

$ch = curl_init();     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Query);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

/*
$search = array("<article", "</article>");
$replace = array("<div", "</div>");
$response = str_replace($search, $replace, $response);
*/

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($response);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$elements = $xpath->query('//article[@class="recherche-aphabetique-item"]/a');

//$elements = $xpath->query('//div[@class="recherche-aphabetique-item"]/a');

count($elements);

var_dump($elements);
?>
```

fiddle to test it :
http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/r9n6-d0j0

I just want to get all "a" nodes that are in "article" nodes with the class "recherche-aphabetique-item".

But it returns me nothing :/.

As you can see in the commented code I've tried to replace html5 elements articles to div, but I got the same behavior.

Thanks four your help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing lots of `DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag` errors - you should use the internal error handling functions of libxml to help fix this perhaps. Also, when I looked at the DOM of the remote site I could not see any `a` tags that would match the XPath query, only `span` tags

```
<?php
$What = 'Call of duty';
$What = urlencode($What);
$Query = 'http://www.jeuxvideo.com/recherche.php?m=9&t=10&q='.$What;

$ch = curl_init();     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Query);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

/* try to suppress errors using libxml */
libxml_use_internal_errors( true );

$dom = new DOMDocument();

/* additional flags for DOMDocument */
$dom->validateOnParse=false;
$dom->standalone=true;
$dom->strictErrorChecking=false;
$dom->recover=true;
$dom->formatOutput=false;

@$dom->loadHTML($response);

libxml_clear_errors();

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$elements = $xpath->query('//article[@class="recherche-aphabetique-item"]/span');

count( $elements );
var_dump( $elements );
?>
```

### output

```
object(DOMNodeList)#97 (1) { ["length"]=> int(94) }
```

You could further simplify this perhaps by trying:

```
$What = 'Call of duty';
$What = urlencode($What);
$Query = 'http://www.jeuxvideo.com/recherche.php?m=9&t=10&q='.$What;

libxml_use_internal_errors( true );
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->validateOnParse=false;
$dom->standalone=true;
$dom->strictErrorChecking=false;
$dom->recover=true;
$dom->formatOutput=false;
@$dom->loadHTMLFile($Query);
libxml_clear_errors();

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$elements = $xpath->query('//article[@class="recherche-aphabetique-item"]/span');
count($elements);
foreach( $elements as $node )echo $node->nodeValue,'<br />';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works as expected with your code.
May the end tag errors were the problems ?
Just a thing that I dont understand, the tags in browser are "a" but they got replaced with "span" when we download the html file...

Comment: The replacement of the "a" tags by "span" prevents me to get the href link.

Comment: looking at the site again using Chrome this time rather than Firefox ( with javascript disabled ) the `a` tags are clearly present which suggests to me that the `a` tags are generated using javascript which presents a problem when scraping data

Comment: Yes, it's replaced with javascript, but I found the way to decode the links that are stored encoded in span class (for example : 1F4D43C3C51F4D43C31E24232C23261F). I'm trying to rewrite the code from JS to PHP actually.